# How to change logo of strapi on admin panel left menu?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I am running the strapi project and need to change strapi login screen logo. I have replaced logo in plugins > user-permissions > admin > src > assets > images > logo_strapi.png and running the command npm run setup --plugins but after that it's not loading content-type data it's just giving me loader only

Comment: I've never used srapi but there something on their docs : https://strapi.io/documentation/advanced/customize-admin.html. Did you have a look there?

Comment: yaa but its only for admin panel and login screen logo does not belong to admin folder. it belongs to users and permission plugin and I can not find the method for setting up the plugins after changing logo

Answer (score 19):

Logo you can overvrite in path -> `./admin/admin/src/assets/images/logo-strapi.png`

**rember** to rebuild project by `npm run build` command

> The AdminUI package source can be easily found in `./node_modules/strapi-admin/src/`.
>
> For example, to change the top-left displayed admin panel's color, `./node_modules/strapi-admin/admin/src/components/LeftMenuHeader/styles.scss` should be overriden by `./admin/src/components/LeftMenuHeader/styles.scss` with your own styles.
>
> Thus, you are replacing the files that would normally be in `node_modules/strapi-admin/admin/src` and directing them to `admin/src/some/file/path`.
>
> To apply your changes you need to rebuild your admin panel
>
> ```
> npm run build
> ```

#### Source

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3604

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/3609/files

Comment: to clarify the path is `./my-project/admin/src/assets/images/logo-strapi.png`

Comment: changing a node_module would just be overwritten after the next install. Which would happen everytime you deploy on a server, for example

Comment: On modern Strapi installations this solution won't work, as pointed out by @SeanMC. The answer by benchvorndaranch is the proper, officially documented solution.

Answer (score 14):

Since this question is a bit older... In the current version of **Strapi (V4)** changing the icon of the left menu works a bit differently (the presented solution is tested with 4.0.6). T*his solution also works for changing the Logo at the Login Screen and the favicon...*

In your project create an `extension` folder under `./yourProjectName/src/admin/`
Within it you can place a new image that should be your new Menu Logo i.e. 'new-menu-logo.png'

Furthermore create an `app.js` file under `./yourProjectName/src/admin/` where you then import the image of the extension folder. Example:

```
// path: ./yourProjectName/src/admin/app.js

import AuthLogo from './extensions/my-new-logo.png';
import MenuLogo from './extensions/new-menu-logo.png';
// import favicon from './extensions/favicon.ico';

export default {
  config: {
    // Replace the Strapi logo in auth (login) views
    auth: {
      logo: AuthLogo,
    },
   // Replace the favicon
    // head: {
    //   favicon: favicon,
    // },
    // Add a new locale, other than 'en'
    locales: ['fr', 'de'],
    // Replace the Strapi logo in the main navigation
    menu: {
      logo: MenuLogo,
    },
    // Override or extend the theme
    theme: {
      colors: {
        alternative100: '#f6ecfc',
        alternative200: '#e0c1f4',
        alternative500: '#ac73e6',
        alternative600: '#9736e8',
        alternative700: '#8312d1',
        danger700: '#b72b1a'
      },
    },
    // Extend the translations
    translations: {
      fr: {
        'Auth.form.email.label': 'test',
        Users: 'Utilisateurs',
        City: 'CITY (FRENCH)',
        // Customize the label of the Content Manager table.
        Id: 'ID french',
      },
    },
   // Disable video tutorials
    tutorials: false,
   // Disable notifications about new Strapi releases
    notifications: { release: false },
  },

  bootstrap() {},
};
```

Finally rebuild the AdminUI with i.e. `yarn build`

Also described at the official docs: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#configuration-options

Comment: @benchvondaranach Did you manage to remove/customize Brand name in `Welcome to Strapi!` and `Log in to your Strapi account` ?

Comment: This is by the official documentation, but does not work. I can change the theme colors, so the app.js is parsed, but logo's remain the default strapi ones.

Answer (score 3):

Per Strapi's documentation, to change the top-left displayed admin panel's logo, add your custom image at `../admin/src/assets/images/logo-strapi.png`.

You have to create these folders if they don't exist `../admin/src/assets/images/` to override the admin's existing styling.

Answer (score 2):

According to the doc https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#customization-options,
you can modify the (logo and css). This is done by writing folders and files in your project folder. These files will overwrite the node module ones.

So, for the logo, in `yourProjectName` you can create a file at this path -> `./yourProjectName/admin/src/assets/images/logo-strapi.png`

This file should overwrite the initial strapi logo.

**rember** to rebuild project by `npm run build` command

Answer (score 1):

*I FIGURED IT OUT!*

**1.) Go Here** https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/core/admin/admin/src/translations/en.json

This shows all the spot where text is and what is currently is.

Here is a picture of the `en.json` file on the original github.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbef9.jpg

**2.) To change text**

Go to your own Strapi backend. Then go to `config > src > admin > app.js`

If you don't have an `app.js` use my code as template to start.

```
export default {
  config: {
    // Override or extend the theme
    theme: {
      colors: {
        alternative100: "#f6ecfc",
        alternative200: "#e0c1f4",
        alternative500: "#ac73e6",
        alternative600: "#9736e8",
        alternative700: "#8312d1",
        danger700: "#b72b1a",
      },
    },
    // // Extend the translations
    translations: {
      en: {
        "app.components.LeftMenu.navbrand.title": "Publishpen",
        "app.components.LeftMenu.navbrand.workplace": "Dashboard",
        "Auth.form.welcome.title": "Frick ya! White label branding!!!:)",
      },
      fr: {
        "Auth.form.email.label": "test",
        Users: "Utilisateurs",
        City: "CITY (FRENCH)",
        // Customize the label of the Content Manager table.
        Id: "ID french",
      },
    },
    // Disable video tutorials
    tutorials: false,
    // Disable notifications about new Strapi releases
    // notifications: { release: false },
  },

  bootstrap() {},
};
```

Here is my folder structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQA2v.png

If you change the text in the `translations` you will change the text in the Strapi admin portal! Just look in the `en.json` (in the original github) for the text you see on the admin page and then update the `app.js`

```
translations: {
  en: {
    "app.components.LeftMenu.navbrand.title": "Publishpen",
    "app.components.LeftMenu.navbrand.workplace": "Dashboard",
    "Auth.form.welcome.title": "Frick ya! White label branding!!!:)",
  }
}
```

**3.) You MUST re-build `npm run build` or `yarn build`**
If your project doesn't rebuild then it will not show on the admin portal.

Comment: The images help people see where things are located in my folder structure. I’m not taking them out.

Comment: created the app.js, pasted in your code, npm run build, not working.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the logo Strapi. Please follow the document bellow:
Step 1: Create file app.js in path : ./src/admin.
If it's exited please ignore this step.
Step 2: Create a folder to store new logo and then copy new logo to here: ./src/admin/extensions

[image: You can follow this structure]

You can follow structure above
Step 3: Replace by new logo by edit the file app.js look like bellow:

```
// path: src/admin/app.js

import Favicon from './extensions/new-favicon.ico';
import MenuLogo from './extensions/new-logo.png'

export default {
  config: {
    // replace favicon with a custom icon
    head: {
      favicon: Favicon,
    },
    // replace logo
    menu: {
      logo: MenuLogo,
    },
  }
}
```

That's all. hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Also watch the filename as well, I edited `app.example.tsx` to no effect for hours and didn't notice the file should be named `app.tsx`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34452716)

Answer (score -1):

I'm very new to Strapi and I was searching exactly how to achieve this. As per the documentation you need to change the image on `./node_modules/strapi-admin/admin/src/assets/images/logo-strapi.png` and run build the administration panel with `npm run setup`

Comment: This is a hack, please see answer above for a proper solution

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the image at ./plugins/users-permissions/admin/src/assets/images/logo_strapi.png.

HTH

Answer (score -2):

Since this question is over a year old now, and might be confusing for some beginners, i think i will answer how i went upon to change it.
This answer uses `yarn` (Do note that the core of the above answers remains same)

Say your project name is my-project, Navigate to `my-project/node_modules/strapi-admin/admin/src/assets/images`

You will find a file called logo-strapi.png (there will be another file with almost similar file name, make sure its a - and not _ ) and replace it with your desired logo. The approx dimens of the old logo as 1100px x 300px , so make sure your new logo also is of similar dimens.

Once you are done, navigate back to my-project directory and terminate any running instance of strapi. If you are on windows, make sure you close all the file explorer windows which might have any of the subfolders of your project open and preferable close any open browser tabs of your admin panel (if there are any open instances, it might give an error while re building) .

Now run `yarn build` and after it finishes building, start your strapi instance in production or development mode as required with `yarn start` or `yarn develop`

Comment: I don't think changing the contents of a node_module's folder is ever a long-term or recommended solution. Another way?